# Custom action defined by config entity

Tags: 8, configuration

I am currently creating a module that allows generating PDFs based on arbitrary entities (or at least nodes). Multiple templates can be defined as config entities. This part already works. I have the config entity set up with create, edit and delete forms and the list.

Now I want to provide a link for each entity of any entity type (i.e. node) like example.com/node/[nid]/pdf/[template_id] that loads the defined template with ID [template_id], generates the PDF and downloads it directly.

What is the correct way? Should I just provide a link through the routing file or is it better to implement a plugin or a custom operation handler or .. I am new to D8 and so I am not aware of all possibilities.

Thanks, j

Comment: That's what controllers are for, getting parameters from a route and generating output. So yes, to get started you need a routing file, where you define the parameters and the controller class and method that should be called.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that. I just wanted to make sure that there is no "Drupal way" that allows extending the functionality of existing entities. I will try that and get back when it works.

Comment: If you put your comment as answer I will accept it. It worked like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what controllers are for, getting parameters from a route and generating output. So yes, to get started you need a routing file, where you define the parameters and the controller class and method that should be called.